# Felted Material Texture

Tags: texturing, photorealism

[image]

So I want to try to recreate a material more like crafting felt which you can see in the image I've shared here. I was not able to find anything on StackExchange and the threads that are on BlenderArtists.org seem to be out of date with the features that current shader nodes have. If it's a highly resource intensive task, are there ways to cheat some of these effects in a simpler way that maintains the essential feel of this?

Comment: Looks like a lot of subsurface scattering to me. Try that first. As for the thread-ish look...

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck? You can use particles or geometry nodes for the fibers sticking out.